# why spring mvc not able to read URL from controller class kept in jar file

Tags: spring-mvc, struts, struts-1

Please note that I have Existing project in struts 1.x and with the following steps I am trying to integrate Spring MVC to it.

I have a maven project which on deployment is able to read servlet and load respective Controller class from **jar file** on server start-up and gives following info about controller class:

[org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping] Rejected bean name 'SSOController': no URL paths identified

Looks like it is not loading URLS hence I am not able to make any restful web service call on it.

my web.xml has following entry :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Dispatcher Servlet has following entries:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ga.action.controller" />

<mvc:resources location = "/resources/" mapping = "/resources/**" />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean> 



<!-- JAXB2 marshaller. Automagically turns beans into xml -->
<bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
<property name="classesToBeBound">
<list>
<value>com.ga.action.controller.PEMUtil</value>
</list>
</property>
 </bean>
```

Controller class code follows:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello.do")
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/")
    public @ResponseBody String  printTokenMessage(
            @RequestParam("nLiveToken") String message, 
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: The bean name has to map to a URL. Please show your controller code.

Comment: Please find controller code above.

Comment: I think the problem lies in your request mapping patterns. Can you please modify your mappings as used in the following link and check? http://javapapers.com/spring/spring-annotation-based-controllers/

Comment: I am using 3.2.3.RELEASE version of spring and using the similar url mapping end result still same.

Answer (score 2):

Use XML configuration instead of @Conteroller annotation for external jar file controllers. Because the @Controller annotation isn't available in the server class loader. 
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/108774-controllers-from-external-jar

Answer (score 0):

Since the exception indicates the use of *BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping* there should be a bean named */hello.do* in your context.

You do use the *@RequestMapping* annotation so I guess you assumed annotation driven handler mapping would be enabled by default. Which isn't the case. If the *ServletDispatcher* finds no handler mapping it will create a *BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping* for you.

If you want to use annotations in your application you should define

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

in your context configuration.

Comment: I did added <mvc:annotation-driven /> but same no URL are getting mapped. Even I have taken "/" insted of Hello.do in web.xml and contoller class still end result remains the same.

Comment: Even after mapping the dispatcher to `/*`?

Comment: Your controller resides in package com.ga.action.controller?

Comment: yes @Bart and the the maven project having Controller class is used as jar file for my web project.